# Send pdf to shared resource using Zoho Deluge

Tags: api, rest, zoho, zoho-deluge

I'm getting attached PDF to invoice in Zoho books. I will use GET request (using `invokeUrl` or `postUrl` functions). I'm getting result already in Postman:

https://gyazo.com/e3a74ff1e5051928ddb162c0e01dbdd8

I'm getting content of PDF in binary format. But I'm stumbling what to do the next. I need to put this pdf now to any shared resource: Zoho Workdrive, Google disk, dropbox etc. I don't know how to do this in Deluge easier. It should be sharable resource (everyone should have access to this link and can download it).

I'm looking for documentation of Zoho API, found a lot examples in other languages like JS. Expect to find optimal (easy and fast as possible) solution in Deluge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
downloadFile = invokeurl
[
    url :"https://books.zoho.com/api/v3/invoices/3675398000000085014/attachment"
    type :GET
    connection:"invoicescom"
];
info "downLoadFile = " + downloadFile;
uploadResponse = zoho.workdrive.uploadFile(downloadFile,"xxxxxxxxx","book1.pdf",FALSE,"workdrivecon");
info "uploadResp = " + uploadResponse;
```